# Update pandas specific row in file without index

Tags: python, pandas

My data.csv file has no rows, because upon saving I used this code:

```
data_pd.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

So now my data file looks like this:

```
PRICE,SIDE,STATUS
40,UP,NEW
30,DOWN,OLD
80,UP,NEW
```

There's no "index". I tried codes like iloc, at, and so on, but didn't work.

How can I change the value of a specific row, for example, row 2 - which is "30,DOWN,OLD" - and I want to change column "SIDE" to "UP" on this row 2.

Code:

```
data_pd = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data_pd.at[2,'SIDE'] = 'UP'
```

I see no errors, but doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Does "print(data_pd.at[2,'SIDE'])" show the new or the old value? Do you write out the CSV file again after that? Does it change in any way?

Comment: iloc stand for integer location.  df.iloc[2,'SIDE'] = 'UP' will not work because 'SIDE' is not an integer and you are selecting the 3rd row due to zero start index in python.  So you will need to do df.iloc[1,2] to change 'DOWN' in the second row, integer location 1, to 'UP'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python default indexing starts from `0`.

If you want to update the 2nd row, you should write

```
data_pd.at[1,'SIDE'] = 'UP'
```

Your code won't do anything as value for `SIDE` in the third row whose index is `2` is already `UP`.